# Where can the implementation of tf.image.resize_bicubic be found?

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to know the kernel that this op is using. I've been looking through the TF source code. The closest I got to was image_ops.cc. Can someone point me to the right place to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python hook is inside:

```
tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops.py
```

The compiler system applies a translation to the operation names;

```
resize_bicubic -> ResizBicubicOP
```

Finally, you can find the Kernel inside:

```
 tensorflow/core/kernels/resize_bicubic_op.cc#L88
```

Comment: How do you know it applies a translation? In particular, in line 807 of image_ops.py, I see this gen_image_ops.resize_bicubic(...), what is this gen_image_ops?